# Not able to access webservice from same network java

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, jboss

My webservice is running on jboss and client is on the tomcat
both client and webservice is running perfect on my local machine.
but if i setup client on another machine, the client program giving an error message 404 not found
I have shared my jboss over network and i am able to access webservice wsdl from another machine using  http:192.168.1.26:8080/FalconServer/SearchService?wsdl
I set the same url in Client code.
but it won't work, any help

Comment: Did you try with http:///192.168.1.26:8080/FalconServer/SearchService?wsdl as you are missing some slashes after http

Comment: Note there should be 2 slashes, SO comment boxes don't seem to like that

Comment: i tried with this url and i am able to see wsdl file from another machine on my network http://192.168.1.26:8080/FalconServer/SearchService?wsdl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to put this as a comment, but i dont seem to find a comment button.
Did you start your jboss binding to your ip address. One way to do that:

run -b